# Fluid Mechanics and Plasmas

Tags: fluid-dynamics, plasma-physics

Can anyone please explain what is difference between movement of a plasma and a fluid.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In a normal fluid like water there is only one thing flowing, which is the water molecules.  In a plasma the electrons and the ions can move separately. Most of the momentum is due to the ions as they are much heavier than the electrons and the relative motion of the positively charged ions and negatively charged  electrons gives rise to an electric current.  There can therefore be momentum and mass flow without a charge current, and a charge current without a mass flow. More generally both occur.